# Assimilation of /ʃ/ to [ɕ] before bunched [ɹ̈]

Tags: american-english, phonetics, consonants, consonant-clusters

I noticed an odd phonetic phenomenon in my own speech that I initially assumed was widespread; then I asked @tchrist about it and he seemed to think it was highly unusual, which made me curious. IANAP (I am not a phonetician) so I'm sorry if I'm bad at explaining this.

Like many American English speakers, I typically pronounce the phoneme /ɹ/ as the "bunched R," sometimes transcribed phonetically as [ɹ̈]. At the start of a word like *rue*, the tip of my tongue doesn't move upward towards the palate, as it would for [ɹ] or retroflex [ɻ]; instead it moves backwards, making my tongue bunch up somewhere near the back of my palate. The word *shoe,* by contrast, begins very differently. At the start of that word, the tip of my tongue does move upward to make the usual [ʃ] sound.

One would (quite naively) think that the initial /ʃɹ/ in *shrew* would just be a combination of these two sounds, i.e. [ʃɹ̈], with the tip of the tongue first moving up to create a [ʃ] and then backwards to make a bunched [ɹ̈]. Indeed, I certainly *can* make those sounds in order. But this isn't how I say the word *shrew.* In that word, as in *rue,* the tip of my tongue doesn't move upwards towards my palate at all. Instead I pronounce the initial /ʃ/ differently, more using the back of my tongue, as [ɕ] or something very close to that. If I make myself add a vowel (instead of an [ɹ̈]) after this sound, it sounds like [Wikipedia's recording of [ɕ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolo-palatal_fricative) rather than [their recording of [ʃ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_postalveolar_fricative#Voiceless_palato-alveolar_fricative); it sounds different, albeit subtly, from the /ʃ/ in *shoe.*

The same thing happens across syllable boundaries, as in *mushroom* or *fisher*, and across word boundaries, as in *push right*; it also happens to the corresponding voiced phoneme /ʒ/, so that the word *measure* ends in something like [ʑɹ̩̈] (with the [ɹ̈] being syllabic). It *doesn't* happen when the /ʃ/ is part of /t͡ʃ/, though, so in *pitch right* the word *pitch* ends in more or less an ordinary [t͡ʃ], not [t͡ɕ].

Presumably this is some sort of assimilation, since the tongue position of [ɕ] seems to be closer to that of [ɹ̈] than [ʃ] is; it stops you from having to move the tip of your tongue around as much and keeps the tongue body further back in the mouth. But I can't seem to find any resources documenting this phenomenon.

So: am I the only one who does this? I'm about 95% sure I'm not just imagining things.

Comment: American /r/ is often rounded, however it's produced in the mouth. As a result, there is a contrast, often neutralized, between American initial /tr/ as in _trip_ and initial /tʃ/ as in _chip_. When my son was about 6 (and already familiar with Star Wars terms, I asked him what _snow troopers_ did. His answer was "Choop snow, I guess". He had neutralized the contrast (or not distinguished it yet in his speech).

Comment: I'm confused by your usage of [ɕ] ,the symbol for the alveolo-palatal sibilant, to denote what I presume is a "bunched sh" with no palatal element. The sibilant noise of [ɕ] should be higher-pitched than of [ʃ]. If I try reproducing what I think you're describing (something like [ɹ̝̥]? a voiceless bunched-r that is raised slightly to produce frication), the result is lower-pitched than [ʃ].

Comment: @awelotta I think you're right that I was mistranscribing it; if I make a spectrogram, the sound at the start of *shrew* is indeed lower in frequency than the sound at the start of *shoe.*  "A voiceless bunched-r that is raised slightly to produce frication" is exactly the sound I'm talking about.

Comment: I should note that the "bunched R" sound itself can be articulated in different places; the one I use seems to correspond to ["Type 3" in this diagram.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Lyra-Magloughlin/publication/236663191/figure/fig8/AS:634154421067778@1528205604267/The-Delattre-and-Freeman-1968-taxonomy-with-examples-of-bunched-a-and-retroflex.png)